# Unable to get Visual Studio 2010 on Win7 64bit to remember Visual Source Safe password

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, visual-sourcesafe

Whenever I open a solution that is under VSS control, I get prompted for my password, even before I've tried to actually change a file.  That never used to happen when we were on WinXP.  I've spent several days searching and keep finding the same "solutions" but it never works.  Here's what I've tried:

Adding my credentials to the Windows 7 Credentials Manager.

Adding SSUSER and SSPWD environment variables.

Having VSS use my network login name isn't an option.

Anyone got any other suggestions?

Comment: remove the pwd from vss?  I did that over here because the only staff using vss are developers and I didn't want them forgetting it on me.  might not work in your shop...

Comment: I ended up punting and reinstalling VSS.  I probably should have done that sooner but I really wanted to understand what went wrong so I could avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Create an AutoHotKey that automatically insert your password whenever VSS ask for it :-)

Comment: :)  That would probably have worked.  No necessary now tho.  I will keep that option in mind for future reference.